# How to add active class on click event in custom list group?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Following is my code of custom list group. How can i have active class add upon click on the item list.

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#!" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-2 h5">List group item heading</h5>
      <small>3 days ago</small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-2">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius
      blandit.</p>
    <small>Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
  </a>
  <a href="#!" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-2 h5">List group item heading</h5>
      <small class="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-2">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius
      blandit.</p>
    <small class="text-muted">Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
  </a>
  <a href="#!" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-2 h5">List group item heading</h5>
      <small class="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-2">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius
      blandit.</p>
    <small class="text-muted">Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
  </a>
</div>
```

Although it will be in my react-app the solution in jquery will be fine by me.

Comment: give a look to https://api.jquery.com/addClass/ for assistance to remove the class use https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: Plain Javascript: `element.classList.add('className')` and `element.classList.remove('className')` should do the trick.

Comment: The bigger issue here is that as anchor tag has many children, upon click event I am not able to get the reference to it but rather to either p tag or h tag, hence not able to add active class to a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding handler to the click event of the `list-group-item` class

The following should work

```
$(".list-group-item").click(function(){

   var listItems = $(".list-group-item"); //Select all list items

   //Remove 'active' tag for all list items
   for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {                    
      listItems[i].classList.remove("active");
   }

   //Add 'active' tag for currently selected item
   this.classList.add("active");
});
```